# Golang ковертация даты, html

Tags: golang

подскажите как правильно конвертировать дату(10 мarch) на русский язык(10 марта) в go.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал через мапы

```
func main() {

    monthsMap := map[string]string{
        "January":   "января",
        "February":  "февраля",
        "March":     "марта",
        "April":     "апреля",
        "May":       "мая",
        "June":      "июня",
        "July":      "июля",
        "August":    "августа",
        "September": "сентября",
        "October":   "октября",
        "November":  "ноября",
        "December":  "декабря",
    }

 date := time.Date(2023, 3, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)

russianMonth:=monthsMap[date.Month().String()]

formattedDate := fmt.Sprintf("%d %s %d года", date.Day(), russianMonth, date.Year())

fmt.Println(formattedDate)
}
```